# What kind of material is recommended to abrade a ring to reduce glossy finish?

Tags: metalworking, metal, jewelry

I have a ring I was told is made of 'white gold' that has a glossy, mirror-like finish that is a problem for two reasons: 1) it easily scratches and 2) I'd prefer the ring to be less flashy/visually loud.

What material is recommended to abrade the outside of the ring to change it from more glossy to more matte? A fine-grit sandpaper, perhaps? Would that have any effects on the surface, like making it feel rough (hopefully not)? Also, if this goes wrong could it be polished again? Thanks for any advice.

[image: ring with finish]
[image: ring material based on stamp]

The 585 in the hallmark appears to mean 14-carat gold, a measure of purity. I don't know what the "Ωλ 85" means, but one website suggests it represents the manufacturer. The ring is from Greece.

> The second characteristic ‒which is not mandatory for Greece‒ reflects
> the identity of the manufacturer, in the form of letters, symbols or
> numbers. This is a special feature, which is at the manufacturer's
> discretion whether to engrave it on the jewelry or not.

https://kiriakosgofas.gr/ti-einai-ta-karatia-xrusou/

Comment: Can you show the stamp on the inside in an additional photo? It should show what the ring is made of and help inform how to handle this question; if it's only plated, any treatment you might attempt will likely result in damaging or removing the plating.

Comment: Good point, that's added above now. I don't know how to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring appears to be solid so polishing with various grades of silicon carbide paper ( wet  or dry ) will provide various degrees of matte like finish. Good hardware store or auto pars store will have these papers. I suspect 320 grit will be close to what you want. For one small component like the ring, hand polishing should be satisfactory. I would start with 180 or 240 grit; they may even be satisfactory . Remember , they work by removing metal. Or a cooperative local jeweler may do it at lost cost.